Relationship between standard Big-O and Big-O in probability.
In this paper, the result of Theorem 1 has the form:
$$Pr[L \le C_1t^{-3}] > C_2,$$
where $t$ is iteration time, $C_1, C_2>0$ and $L$ is loss function of difference between target and output. They say its convergence rate is $O(t^{-3})$. Regarding this, I found a definition, Big O in probability notation. Additionally they proved its lower bound $\Omega(t^{-3})$ in Theorem 6:
$$L \ge ct^{-3}, $$
where $c>0$. (I refer to Big O notation for $O$, $\Omega$ and $\Theta$ notation).
From these, they claimed that convergence rate of learning the target is $\Theta(t^{-3})$.
As I know "a function $f$ is $\Theta(t^{-3})$" means "$f$ is both $O(t^{-3})$ and $\Omega(t^{-3})$", here $O$ is defined in Big O notation, not in probability.
However, I am confused since the author have proved only Big O in probability notation.
Does Big O in probability notation imply standard Big O notation?

No, consider $X_{n}=0$ with probability $1-n^{-1}$, $X_{n}=n$ with probability $n^{-1}$. Apparently $X_{n}=O_{p}(1)$ but it remains unbounded. For the content you mentioned, "rate of convergence" of random objects is a bit different, my understanding is that the author is trying to say $t^{3}L=O_{p}(1)$ where the rate cannot be improved.

@Q9y5 Why does $O_p(1)$, not $\Omega(t^{-3})$, say the rate cannot be improved?

You are correct about the "cannot be improved" part is given by "$\Omega(t^{-3})$." The condition $L\geq ct^{-3}$ implies $\mathbb{P}(L\geq ct^{-3})=1>c_{2}$ for any $c_{2}<1$, a similar condition as $O_{p}$ with the difference that $L$ is now bounded from below in probability. I'm not sure if there's similar notation $\Omega$ and $\Theta$ here, so I simply refer to as a combination of $O_{p}$ with "cannot be improved," to emphasize that $t^{3}$ is not only sufficient to control $L$, any higher order of normalization (say, $f(t)L$ with $f(t)\gg t^{3}$) will lead to a degenerate limit.
